# Pass parameter to Javascript function from ASP code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a long process and I want to show a user a progress bar where I pass a parameter (percentage) to a Javascript function in my Webform with masterpage.

I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function updateProgress(percentage) {          
            document.getElementById('ProgressBar').style.width = percentage+"%";
        }
</script>
```

and:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active progress-success" style="height: 43px">
      <div id="ProgressBar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" runat="server"
          aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
      </div>
</div>
```

In my code-behind, I have this to pass a parameter to the function:

```
// Report progress >> ~ 18%                   
string updateProgress = "18";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "updateProgress", "updateProgress('" + updateProgress + "');", true);
```

As I run the code, the progressbar never moves from 0%. I would like to keep updating the percentage completion from code behind until it reaches 100% by calling the function again with new parameters.

I have looked through forums but I cant see what I need to to to make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your server code registers a script that will be executed **when you return a response** to the client. In a web application the server and client are disconnected *most of the time*. It's like sending a letter. The client is waiting for your response, you can't give them status updates as you're writing.

Comment: good question. Do you access a database in the process?

Comment: Forgive my lack of expertise when it comes to Javascript. @RobH I'm open to any other ways to achieve what I require.

Comment: @lalborno. Yes, financial calculations are performed during the process and there are numerous queries to a number of tables.

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau - You can either show a nondescript loading icon e.g. from [ajaxloader.info](http://ajaxload.info/) while the server is doing its stuff or you'll have to get more advanced and poll for status updates from your client.

Comment: @RobH The ajaxloader won't work for me as it doesn't tell how much progress has been achieved. Will read about SignalR and try the 2nd recommendation.

Comment: You don't need SignalR. You can achieve it with `WebMethod`s and JavaScript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this way

```
    string updateProgress = "18%";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "updateProgress", "updateProgress('" + updateProgress + "');", true);
```

Script AS

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateProgress(percentage) {
        document.getElementById("ProgressBar").style.width = percentage;
    }
  </script>
```

ASPX page

```
   <div class="progress progress-striped active progress-success" style="height: 43px">
        <div id="ProgressBar" runat="server" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"
            style="width: 0px;" >
        </div>
    </div>
```