# C# how to retrieve Stripe Token from the Form.Submit

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I ask how to retrieve the token from the coding/server side based on this script?

```
    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
        // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: What docs did you follow to build the above function?

Comment: The same was as any form input, are you having trouble with the token specifically or do you need to know how html forms work?

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks for the reply, I need to know how html forms work, based on the code above I assumed that the form.submit will submit the var form, how to fetch it from the server side? especially the token.id. Thanks!

Comment: @mjwills I am following this https://stripe.com/docs/elements

Comment: Is this MVC or web forms?

Comment: @mjwills Web Forms, not MVC

Comment: Have a squiz at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25131620/34092 .

Comment: I assume this is a standard aspx page with code-behind?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes it is

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the link, but isnt that from ASP code-behind to Java Script?, I need the opposite :D, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic example of submitting a webform with javascript and accessing the form collection on the server. I have hard-coded the stripe token value, I'm assuming you have that part covered.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication11.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <button onclick="stripeTokenHandler('some token value');">Submit Me</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
    <script>
        function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
            var form = document.getElementById('form1');
            var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripetoken');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token);
            form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

            // Submit the form
            form.submit();
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebApplication11
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                //any form inputs can be obtained with Request.Form[]
                Debug.WriteLine(Request.Form["stripetoken"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```